# web.xml, security constraint, where do you declare that a user has x role besides declaring it in web.xml?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, web.xml, security-constraint

Hi I'm just learning about the deployment descriptor and I'm wondering about how whatever is using the security constraint knows whether the user is of a certain role, where do you declare the role for the user? for example in an android application, but clear this doubt for me please, you have to give each user a role right? where do you do that? I'm using google cloud storage and app engine